# Feynman-Kac formula for $\mu(t,x)=-\frac{1}{1-t}, \sigma(t,x)=1$ and $g(t,x)=x^2$

Tags: option-pricing, itos-lemma, feynman-kac

Consider the following PDE on $[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}$:
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}+\mu(t,x) \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}+  \frac12 \sigma^2(t,x)\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} = 0 \\
F(T,x)=g(x)
\end{cases}
$$
with $\mu(t,x)=-\frac{1}{1-t}, \ \sigma(t,x)=1, \ g(x)=x^2$.

Question: What is the solution of the problem?

I know that if $X=\{X_t: t \geq 0\}$ satisfies
$$dX_t=\mu(t,X_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t)dW_t$$
then (by Feynman-Kac's theorem)
$$F(t,x)=\mathbb{E}^Q[g(X_T)|X_t=x]$$

I know that 
$$X_T=X_t-\int_{t}^T\frac{1}{1-s}ds+\int_{t}^TdW_s$$
but then I don't know how to deal with $(X_T)^2$.
How can I get the solution?

Comment: Try to expand $X_T^2$ and see what you can have.

Comment: That's what I've tried but I get stuck...

I know that $$\int_{t}^TdW_s=W_T-W_t$$ but I don't know for example how to get rid of $$\int_{t}^T \frac{1}{1-s}ds$$